# 'who' or 'whom'?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

I'm learning relative pronoun and I'm using Cliffs Toefl as a reference book. As this book says, relative pronoun **who** should be followed by a verb and **whom** should be followed by a noun. According to this rule the sentence should be:

> *Please vote for the member **whom** you believe has done the most for our village.*

I'm still learning English and I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing, but despite what the rule says, the sentence with **who** sounds correct to me.

> *Please vote for the member **who** you believe has done the most for our village.*

I believe the clause **you believe** immediately after the relative pronoun **who/whom** is making it hard for me to understand the sentence because I'm kind of new to this kind of sentence pattern.

I would be obliged if someone would help me to understand and to learn what's actually happening in this sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Please vote for the member* [*who you believe* [ ___ *has done the most for our*
> *village*]].

The element in outer brackets is the relative clause modifying "member".

Within the relative clause is the embedded "has done ..." clause, in inner  brackets, in which the relative pronoun functions as subject, marked by the '___' notation, called gap.  Subjective "who" is thus correct.

Note that in general most people use "who" irrespective of its function (except when it's object of a fronted preposition).